# File upload not working if the form link on Gmail is accessed on IE 9

Tags: forms, file-upload, internet-explorer-9, gmail

My application sends email to users with a link to the application page where the user can upload a file for a business requirement. If the email is sent to a gmail id and when the user open the email in IE9 and clicks on the link, it navigates to the application page and when he tries to upload the file, it fails. There are no error messages shown on IE9 developer console.

1. The upload works fine in all browsers other than IE9.
2. If the user opens the link by right click -> Open in New tab, then the upload works fine
3. If the User clicks on the link directly, which by default Gmail will open in new tab on IE9, the upload fails.

I verified the URLs in either cases and there are no differences. I tried playing around with target attribute for the link (new, blank etc) and nothing helps.

Copy pasting the link in a new tabs works. But not clicking on the link

Answer (score 1):

This is a IE9 issue - apparently you can work around it by setting IE9 in IE8 mode in Gmail (nice huh!)

Anyway there's a good write up here (and link to a demo project showing the issue):

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/457

> IE9 <strike>(and possibly other IE versions)</strike> doesn't allow submitting a HTML form programmatically (neither via form.submit() nor via button.click()), if the containing document has been opened via a Gmail link.